# Showing relatively compact and finite dimension

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, compactness, lp-spaces

I have a question where I have to show:

> 1. Prove that a normed linear space is finite-dimensional if and only if every bounded subset is relatively compact.
> 2. Show that the spaces $C[0,1]$ and $L^{2}(0,2 \pi)$ are infinite dimensional.

Now for the first part I'm not entirely sure if I understand the concept of relative compactness well. To show a set is relatively compact is it enough to take a sequence in it and show that it has a convergent subsequence? Would that imply that the closure of the set is compact (which is what I understand is the definition of relative compactness or precompactness)? If this is true here is my proof.

1. Take any bounded subset B of a finite dimensional space X. Let
   $x^{(n)}$ be a sequence in B. Then due to equivalence of norms on
   finite dimensional spaces we have an $M$ and $K$ such that:

   $K \geq \sup_n ||x^{(n)}|| \geq \sup_n M \max_{k=1,2..N}
   \{|\alpha_k^{(n)}|\}  > |\alpha_k^{(m)}|\quad \forall k$

   Where $x^{(n)} = \sum_{i\leq N} e_i \alpha^{(n)}_i$ where
   $\{e_i\}_{i\leq N}$ is a normalized finite basis. Then
   $|\alpha_k^{(m)}|$ has a convergent subsequence by Bolzano Weierstrass
   and we can inductively find a subsequence of $x^{(n)}$ with convergent
   coordinates. Now since convergence in coordinates implies
   convergence for finite dim sequences we have found a convergent
   subsequence and I think we are done(?).

   For the other direction we can see that the closed unit ball is
   compact so the space must be finite dimensional.
2. For C[0,1] I take a sequence in the unit ball $f_n(t) = t^n$,
   suppose it has a convergent subsequence in sup norm then the
   sequence must also converge pointwise, but then the sequence must
   converge to $1_{\{1\}}$ which is not in C[0,1] hence can't be in
   closure of the unit ball either.

   For Lp we take again a sequence in the closed unit ball given by
   $f_n(x) = 1_{[0, 1/n]} x n$ again if we have a convergent
   subsequence then that convergent subsequence has a subsequence that
   converges pointwise (to the same limit), but that limit clearly must
   be 0, but $||f_n(x)|| = \sqrt{1/2}$ hence contradiction again, so
   closure of unit ball is not compact. Thank you in advance for the
   help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition you provide for relative compactness is the definition of compactness. We say a set is relatively compact if it's closure is compact. In terms of sequences, we have the following definition:

**Definition:** $A$ is $\textit{relatively compact}$ if for each sequence in $\overline{A}$, there is a convergent subsequence in $\overline{A}$.

I think there is a much simpler proof for 1. Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional, then there exists $T: V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ an isometric isomorphism for some $n$. Let $A\subset V$ be bounded and note that $T^{-1}\cdot T(\overline{A})=\overline{A}$. Note that $T(\overline{A})$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it's compact. Therefore, $T^{-1}\cdot T(\overline{A})$ is compact.

The other parts of your answer are correct.

Comment: Hi! In my proof I was referecing the following theorem:
 
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $S \subset X$. The following are equivalent:
i. $S$ is relatively compact.
ii. For all sequences $\left(s_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $S$, there is a subsequence $\left(s_{n_{k}}\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges in $X$.

bearing that in mind would my proof be correct? I took a sequence in the bounded subset and showed it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Oh yes. It has a convergent subsequence in $X$, but not in $S$. I thought that's what you were saying.

Comment: Alright, great, thank you very much for the help and your proof!